# CSS for body tags strangely affected google map canvas

Tags: css, google-maps

I have the following code snippet

```
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
</body>
```

That code will not show the map on screen unless I add the following CSS styles

```
<style type="text/css">
html {
    height: 100%
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
</style>
```

I think that the `style` for `map_canvas` tag is enough for the map to show, but it was clearly wrong. Can you explain it for me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use a percentage value for the height of the map, this value can only be calculated when the parent-element (e.g. the body) also has a height set with CSS(this behaviour may differ depending on the used DOCTYPE)